# Vim how to output text when i press CTRL + C While something else is bound to CTRL + C (Linux)

Tags: linux, vim

I Hot This Thing I Wanna have in vim. Basicly when i press ctrl + c i wanna save the file and that was done ez by just adding

```
:nmap <c-s> :w<CR>
:imap <c-s> <Esc>:w<CR>a
```

in my **.vimrc** file. However nothing changes in my vim window. So is there a way to make vim say in the bottom like:

> File Saved :)

I Would imagine that it is probobly someting like binding two things to ctrl + s an so bind some sort of print command to ctrl + s.
I don't know so much about vim or like vim load script thing **.vimrc** stuff. So plz help to get ctrl + s to save and print that it has been saved!

EDIT:

I Have Noticed That the problem y the vim text does not show up is becouse if you are in insert mode while you press ctrl + s then the **--INSERT--** text covers the vim text

Answer (score 0):

```
:nnoremap <C-s> :w<CR>:echo 'File saved.'<CR>
:inoremap <C-s> <Esc>:w<CR>:echo 'File saved.'<CR>a
```

But why bother? Vim already tells you that:

[image]

Comment: But if you are in insert it does not tell you.

Comment: If you are in insert mode you go back to normal mode and you write your file from there.

Answer (score 0):

It could be

```
 inoremap <c-s> <c-o>:w<cr><c-o>:echom "file saved"<cr>
 nnoremap <c-s> :w<cr>:echom "file saved"<cr>
```

but I suspect nothing like this is required as I already have a message when I save a file with vim.

PS: here, `i_CTRL-O` is better than `<esc>`+ `a` that may move your cursor.